# Show posts only from specific CPT Taxonomy Category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched high and low and applied all of the solutions I've found here on Stackoverflow with no luck so trying a post to see if someone could assist me...

I am trying to display the posts that sit under a category in my custom post type taxonomy.

The CPT is called "Fabrics" and the taxonomy is called "Type" - Under "Type" I have a category called "Lycra"

I want to display all of the posts that exist under "Lycra"

Here is the code I have so far, but it just lists all of the posts under Fabrics:

```
<?php
$cat_terms = get_terms(
               array(
    'post_type' => 'fabrics',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 9999999,
    'orderby' =>  'date',
    'order' => 'DES',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  'lycra',
        ),
    ),
)
            );
if( $cat_terms ) :
    echo '<ul class="fabric-listing">';
    foreach( $cat_terms as $term ) :?>
<li class="each-fabric">
     <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term );?>">
     <img src="<?php the_field('imagecat', $term); ?>">     
        <div class="term-name">
                     <?php echo $term->name; ?>  
                </div>
    </a>
    </li>
     <?php   
wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
endif; 
?>
```

What am I missing here? Any help is super appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use get_posts and not get_terms

```
$cat_terms = get_posts(
   array(
    'post_type' => 'fabrics',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' =>  'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  'lycra',
        ),
    ),
)
```